# How can I fix this Armature?

Tags: armature, bones

i need help, how can i change them to bones?

[image]

Comment: maybe select your armature and check what display options are enabled in the Properties panel > Object Data > Viewport Display > Display As. Or your bones may be customized?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply,

but it looks like the FBX exporter has exported the asset wrong.
I have an project in Unity where my fbx of original asset is broken, i was trying to export the asset object as fbx but if i import it in blender it shows like upper. BTW the Armature list shown as here, any idea how i can change this?:
[image]

Oh after fbx export i used fbx converter from autodesk to convert them to binary fbx file.